# How to append a list with another list as input for a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The idea is to treat each element in list y as input for a function (generating a sequence in this case) and append the output of the function to parallel sublist in list x.

```
x = [['a'],['b'],['c']]
y = [2,3,1]
```

The desired output would be:

```
z = [['a','seq_1'],['a','seq_2'], ['b','seq_1'],['b','seq_2'],['b','seq_3'], ['c','seq_1']]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what 'seq_1' represents?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Answer (score 2):

I made a code for you.

```
x = [['a'], ['b'], ['c']]
y = [2, 3, 1]

z = []
for x1, y1 in zip(x, y):
    for i in range(y1):
        z.append(x1 + [f'seq_{i + 1}'])
print(z)
```